# Japanese filename is getting garbled while extracting

Tags: java, csv, outlook, unzip, zipstream

I am zipping a .csv file as follows:

```
fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(csvFile);
final ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(csvFile.getname());
            zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024];
            int size = fileInputStream.read(buffer);
            while (size != -1) 
        {
                zipOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, size);
                size = fileInputStream.read(buffer);
        }
```

The filename also contains japanese/chinese characters
On extracting with winzip/ 7-zip the extracted .csv file name is not garbled but when default windows extracter is used the filename is garbled.

Comment: Do you use the same computer for zipping and unzipping? The zip file format does not know about the character encoding of file names.

Comment: No the file is zipped and emailed

Comment: Hi I used mimiutility to encode the filename in shiftjs , it works fine now in case the attachment is downloaded from outlook web access, but doesnt extract correctly when downloaded from outlook 2013.Any ideas?

Comment: My idea is, that the zip file format does not know about the character encoding of file names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had used :

String fileName = MimeUtility.encodeText(filename,"SJIS",null);

and then it seemed to work fine on systems where the default language was japanese.